# [HTML][Javascript][Canvas] Can't get polygon function to work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shapes, polygons

I'm trying to draw an octagon via canvas but can't get it to display.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="lab5.js"> </script>
  <title> Lab 5 </title>
</head>

<body onload="drawing1(); drawing2(); drawing3();">
  <h1> Canvas </h1>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface1" width="700" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface2" width="350" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface3" width="350" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// drawing 3

function drawing3() {
  var drawingSurface=document.getElementById("drawingSurface3");
  var ctx = drawingSurface.getContext("2d");
  var numberOfSides = 8,
  var size = 20,
  var Xcenter = 50,
  var Ycenter = 50;

  ctx.fillstyle="black"
  cxt.beginPath();
  cxt.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));

  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    cxt.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
  }

  cxt.stroke();
}
```

I assume I'm missing something, but I haven't got a clue as to what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
function drawing3() {
  var drawingSurface=document.getElementById("drawingSurface3");
  var ctx = drawingSurface.getContext("2d");
  var numberOfSides = 8;
  var size = 20;
  var Xcenter = 50;
  var Ycenter = 50;

  ctx.fillstyle="black"
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));

  for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo (Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides), Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides));
  }

  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Lab 5 </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="drawing3()">
  <h1> Canvas </h1>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface1" width="700" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface2" width="350" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="drawingSurface3" width="350" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

There were commas when defining new variables with `var`, they were replaced by `;`.  There are several mispelled `ctx`.